# Tim Prebble's mic stands.

Tags: microphone-stand, travel, portable

[image]

Anybody know what these are called?
I really dig the reverse-folding legs, and the fact that they look like they weigh half a pound at most.  In fact, they look kinda like re-purposed cheapie music stands, but I barely trust those things to hold up a script, let alone expensive mics.

Thanks.

..W..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manfrotto 5001B Nano Black light stand  http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/612771-REG/Manfrotto_5001B_5001B_Nano_Black_Light.html

They are great.  It is threaded for a pistol grip on the top, very very light, collapses down to a nice tight parcel and the wide base when fully open makes them pretty sturdy.

Plus they are not outrageously priced.

PS I think these stands were Noise Jockey's find originally (or at least I saw it on his site first)
http://www.noisejockey.net/blog/2009/07/07/lightweight-mic-stands-in-the-field/

Comment: Mafrotto, that may be the best name I've ever heard.

Comment: thanks to Nathan for the original post - I wouldn't have known of these stands otherwise, and they weight about a quarter of my other stands!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the post with everything described:
http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/safe-travel-with-gear-2